# ERROR pool.ConnectionPool [main] - Unable to create initial connections of pool

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, rundeck

I want to use a MySQL database locally.
Rundeck worked correctly with the default parameters but it no longer starts with MySQL installed as well as the parameters defined in /etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties (below).
You'll also find below some of the logs contained in /var/log/rundeck/rundeck.log

MySQL : Server version: 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 (Ubuntu)

I reinstalled the DB from scratch, changed the authentication settings, and installed the MySQL JDBC Driver as mentioned in the https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/mysql.html#configuring-rundeck doc.

```
#loglevel.default is the default log level for jobs: ERROR,WARN,INFO,VERBOSE,DEBUG
loglevel.default=INFO
rdeck.base=/var/lib/rundeck

#rss.enabled if set to true enables RSS feeds that are public (non-authenticated)
rss.enabled=false
# change hostname here
grails.serverURL=http://URL:4440
#dataSource.dbCreate = none

dataSource.driverClassName = org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
dataSource.url = jdbc:mysql://myserver/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
dataSource.username = rundeckuser
dataSource.password = password

grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart=true

# Encryption for key storage
rundeck.storage.provider.1.type=db
rundeck.storage.provider.1.path=keys

rundeck.storage.converter.1.type=jasypt-encryption
rundeck.storage.converter.1.path=keys
rundeck.storage.converter.1.config.encryptorType=custom
rundeck.storage.converter.1.config.password=e4ae51530100e549
rundeck.storage.converter.1.config.algorithm=PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
rundeck.storage.converter.1.config.provider=BC

# Encryption for project config storage
rundeck.projectsStorageType=db

rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.type=jasypt-encryption
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.path=projects
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.config.password=e4ae51530100e549
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.config.encryptorType=custom
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.config.algorithm=PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.config.provider=BC

rundeck.feature.repository.enabled=true
```

```
[2023-10-04T09:55:12,015] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool [main] - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=myserver)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:myserver, port:3306. myserver
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:192) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1385) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:635) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:744) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:676) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:483) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.44.jar!/:?]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.afterPropertiesSet(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:164) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.<init>(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:108) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.jdbc.connections.DataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.proxy(DataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.java:100) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-7.3.3.jar!/:?]
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.jdbc.connections.DataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.create(DataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.java:93) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-7.3.3.jar!/:?]
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.jdbc.connections.CachedDataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.create(CachedDataSourceConnectionSourceFactory.java:37) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-7.3.3.jar!/:?]
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:38) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5-7.2.2.jar!/:?]
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:23) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5-7.2.2.jar!/:?]
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64) ~[grails-datastore-core-7.3.3.jar!/:?]
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:52) ~[grails-datastore-core-7.3.3.jar!/:?]
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:24) ~[grails-datastore-core-7.3.3.jar!/:?]
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:212) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5-7.2.2.jar!/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:296) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
```

```
/etc/init.d/rundeckd status
○ rundeckd.service - LSB: rundeck job automation console
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/rundeckd; generated)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2023-10-04 09:47:58 CEST; 1s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 2227 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/rundeckd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2360 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/rundeckd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2236 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1min 27.583s

Oct 04 09:47:25 SI-RUNDECK systemd[1]: Starting LSB: rundeck job automation console...
Oct 04 09:47:25 SI-RUNDECK rundeckd[2227]:  * Starting rundeckd
Oct 04 09:47:25 SI-RUNDECK rundeckd[2227]:    ...done.
Oct 04 09:47:25 SI-RUNDECK systemd[1]: Started LSB: rundeck job automation console.
Oct 04 09:47:58 SI-RUNDECK rundeckd[2366]: start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 2236: No …rocessOct 04 09:47:58 SI-RUNDECK rundeckd[2360]:  * Stopping rundeckd
Oct 04 09:47:58 SI-RUNDECK rundeckd[2360]:    ...done.
Oct 04 09:47:58 SI-RUNDECK systemd[1]: rundeckd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 04 09:47:58 SI-RUNDECK systemd[1]: rundeckd.service: Consumed 1min 27.583s CPU time.
```

Comment: Hi! Try the following dataSource.url parameter on `rundeck-config.properties` file: `jdbc:mariadb://myserver/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it worked by changing the value `dataSource.url = jdbc:mysql://myserver/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false` to `dataSource.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false` despite the fact that the documentation mentions that `myserver` is the localhost.